# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'profile'

Tags: python, django

Trying to update profile picture for student models but i get this error. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'profile'. Idk if it has something to do with the views.py but it probably does.

My views.py for user app:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UpdateProfileForm
from django.contrib import messages
from main.models import Student
from .models import Profile



@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student = request.POST.get('student')
        p_form = UpdateProfileForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=student.profile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Student picture has been updated!')
            return redirect('student_profiles')
    else:
        p_form = UpdateProfileForm()

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form,
        'students': Student.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'user/profiles.html', context)
```

Signals.py:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from main.models import Student
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(student=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def update_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created == False:
        instance.profile.save()
```

Profile model:

```
from main.models import Student
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(
        Student, default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.student.firstname} {self.student.surname} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXJEk.png

And this is my profile.html:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    {% for student in students %}
        <div class="content-section">
            <div class="media">
            <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ student.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading"></h2>
                <p class="text-secondary"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ student.firstname }} {{ student.surname }}</legend>
                    {{ p_form|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Try `p_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)` or `p_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.student.profile)`

Comment: I've updated my answer below, plz take a look if it's a quick fix.

Comment: i had related_name set to ```student``` in my profile models.py. When i changed that, everything worked. Thanks so much Eduardo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I'd try is to hide the `Student` id at the template level and get this information to filter the object later.
For the template I'd add this input:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for student in students %}
        <div class="content-section">
            <div class="media">
            <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ student.profile.image.url }}">
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="account-heading"></h2>
                <p class="text-secondary"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{{ student.firstname }} {{ student.surname }}</legend>

                    <!-- pass student.id for every object at students -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="{{ student.id }}" />

                    {{ p_form|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Then at the `view`:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # student_id comes from the hidden input at the html
        student_id = request.POST.get('student_id')
        # get the student object with its relationships, so now student.profile should work
        student = Student.objects.get(pk=student_id)

        p_form = UpdateProfileForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=student.profile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Student picture has been updated!')
            return redirect('student_profiles')
    else:
        p_form = UpdateProfileForm()

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form,
        'students': Student.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'user/profiles.html', context)
```

I hope this is a simple solution for your issue. I didn't test it, but you get the general idea.

Comment: same error. The messages.success returns No student value passed to POST

Comment: There you go: the problem is at your html template, not at your view. No `student` data is been passed to your `def profile(request):` function.

Comment: it's telling me that the error is on this line: p_form = UpdateProfileForm(   
                    request.POST, request.FILES, instance=student.profile)                               of my views.py

Comment: What's the content of `UpdateProfileForm` class?

Comment: `class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = Profile
       fields = ['image']`

Comment: Even though we'll probably have to make it hidden later: try adding 'student' to `fields` list.

Comment: The error is with both the view and the template, @EduardoGomes.  True, the template is passing nothing to the view, but then even if it did, the line `student = request.POST.get('student')` is just going to return a string, not a Student object, and thus that string will not have a profile attribute.  One could perhaps query to find the student by using what you get back from the POST.

Comment: I think he'd have to work with two `ModelForms`: one for `Student` and another for `Profile`. The `Student` one he could pass only `name` to its `fields` list. He'd then render both forms at the template, but at the view he'd do the query you mentioned to find the `Student` by name and finally pass the related profile to `instance`.

Comment: Or he could use an [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). There are many solutions, but you'll have to choose one @AidanMcIntosh. The problem is you're not getting any form field with a valid `student` data and sending it to your view.